# Backwards quotes in embedded C code

Tags: punctuation, code

I used the csquotes package to make all double quotes curl the right way in the body of my document, but in the embedded code it doesn't work. I tried the slanted quotes and they don't work either.  It's only the leading quotes that are the problem, not the closing ones.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
"This works properly."

\begin{lstlisting}
displayTextLine(1, "This does not work properly");
displayTextLine(1, ``This does not work properly either'');
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `csquotes` does nothing inside `listings`

Comment: For this, most likely, you'll have to set some form of `literate` option.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`csquotes` doesn't work inside `lstlisting`; you can use `literate`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\dbllq}{``}
\newcommand{\dblrq}{''}

\lstset{
  literate={``}{\dbllq}1 {''}{\dblrq}1
}

\begin{document}
"This works properly."

\begin{lstlisting}
displayTextLine(1, "This does not work properly");
displayTextLine(1, ``This works properly'');
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]